# How to make Android product consumable

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project, which I need to make consumable.

On clicking on the purchase button, using below code for consumption.

```
inventory=new Inventory();
mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_SUCCESS),mConsumeFinishedListener1);
```

But it getting 'Null pointer exception for Purchase here in IabHelper class.

```
void consume(Purchase itemInfo) throws IabException {
    checkSetupDone("consume");

    if (!itemInfo.mItemType.equals(ITEM_TYPE_INAPP)) {
        throw new IabException(IABHELPER_INVALID_CONSUMPTION,
                "Items of type '" + itemInfo.mItemType
                        + "' can't be consumed.");
    }

    try {
        String token = itemInfo.getToken();
        String sku = itemInfo.getSku();
        if (token == null || token.equals("")) {
            logError("Can't consume " + sku + ". No token.");
            throw new IabException(IABHELPER_MISSING_TOKEN,
                    "PurchaseInfo is missing token for sku: " + sku + " "
                            + itemInfo);
        }
```

Please let me know if anyone have Idea regarding this.

The code for consumeAsync()

```
public void consumeAsync(Purchase purchase, OnConsumeFinishedListener listener) {
    checkSetupDone("consume");
    List<Purchase> purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
    purchases.add(purchase);
    consumeAsyncInternal(purchases, listener, null);
}

public void consumeAsync(List<Purchase> purchases, OnConsumeMultiFinishedListener listener) {
    checkSetupDone("consume");
    consumeAsyncInternal(purchases, null, listener);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for consumeAsync() method and the exception stack trace?

Comment: Here is the code for consumeAsyc,

public void consumeAsync(Purchase purchase,
   OnConsumeFinishedListener listener) {
  checkSetupDone("consume");
  List<Purchase> purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
  purchases.add(purchase);
  consumeAsyncInternal(purchases, listener, null);
 }



************
public void consumeAsync(List<Purchase> purchases,
   OnConsumeMultiFinishedListener listener) {
  checkSetupDone("consume");
  consumeAsyncInternal(purchases, null, listener);
 }

Comment: Is the code for `consumeAsyncInternal` overloaded? If not, why are you calling it with `consumeAsyncInternal(purchases, listener, null);` in one case and `consumeAsyncInternal(purchases, null, listener);` in another? That inversion of arguments seems like an obvious place to look for a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're using Google's [marketbilling project](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/), which I stumbled across today. I don't know if this is the "standard" way to do in-app billing, but it would have been helpful to know you were using this from the start.

Anyway, the `Inventory` class is also a part of that project. You are creating an empty `Inventory`object when you do the following `inventory=new Inventory();`. It shouldn't be surprising, then, that `inventory.getPurchase(SKU_SUCCESS)` will return null:

```
/** Returns purchase information for a given product, or null if there is no purchase. */
public Purchase getPurchase(String sku) {
    return mPurchaseMap.get(sku);
}
```

You are passing that value to `mHelper.consumeAsync`, which eventually passes it to `consume` as `itemInfo`. When consume executes the check `!itemInfo.mItemType.equals(ITEM_TYPE_INAPP)`, you get the null pointer exception.

In short, pass a valid `Purchase` object to the `consumeAsync` method.

Comment: Yes Jerry you are right, Actually I had not added the consume functionality in Main activity. Now I have added:

 mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener); after Ihelper setup. It's working fine now.

Comment: @u_pendra I'm glad you got it working. Please accept the answer if you found it helpful, stackoverflow works best with feedback. See the ["How do I ask questions here?" faq entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for a little more detail.